# Who are historical proponents of moral anti-realism?

Tags: ethics, history-of-philosophy

I was wondering about the history of moral anti-realism. It seems to me that realism has been the dominant view since Plato, with anti-realism being given systematic attention only in the last 100 years. However this could just be due to my limited scholarship.

Anybody know more about who has advanced antirealism in the past?

Thanks --- Rory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nietzsche - of course. TBH I can't think of anyone else, it was a simply theistic time ha!

You could I suppose look into zen Buddhism - the answer there would be complex, and perhaps not to your taste, but there is the argument / assertion that morality is a dualistic way of thinking. Of coure they don't condone [nor accept - there is still a [vinaya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vinaya) in Japanese Buddhism] immorality, but there is the famous answer of Bodhidharma ['official' founder of zen] to an Emperor who asks about the [merit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merit_%28Buddhism%29) of all his good deeds

> No merit whatsoever.

HTH a little.